# Building of Docker image from Dockerfile making error "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument"

Tags: docker

I am trying to build Docker image by using Jenkins pipeline script. When I am running the following code,

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t spacestudykubernetes /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd/pipeline
```

I added this command in inside Jenkins pipeline job shell script. There "cd" command will not work. Change directory not working in shell script. Because of that without changing directly, I gave the command with full path. According to your command it will work (after putting change directory) . I am trying to execute from cicd folder, not from pipeline folder. Dockerfile is resides in pipeline folder.

**My Jenkins pipeline script**

```
pipeline 
{
    agent any
    stages 
        {
            stage ('imagebuild')
                {
                    steps
                        {

sh 'docker build -f Dockerfile -t spacestudykubernetes /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd/pipeline'

                        }
                }
        }
}
```

**Error**

I am getting the error like the following,

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

I am not running from direct folder where Dockerfile is resides. My Dockerfile is resides in **pipeline** folder. That is my code checked out from SVN. And I am trying to run this command from **cicd** folder. And I gave the full path with -f argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss context directory at the end of command line. Usually it is simply `.`. This directory will serve as root for all paths in `Dockerfile` whenever you use `ADD/COPY` and also as a build context - meaning its content will be zipped and passed to docker daemon when build is executed.

```
cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd/pipeline
docker build -f Dockerfile -t spacestudykubernetes .
```

Comment: Actually I added this command in inside jenkins pipeline job shell script. There "cd" command will not work. Change directory not working in shell script. Because of that without changing directlry , I gave the command with full path. According to your command it will work (after putting change directory) . I am trying to execute from cicd folder. not from pipeline folder. Dockerfile is resides in pipeline folder. I hope that you understood my problem. And Thank you for your response sir.

Comment: Not a problem, man, i've just put `cd` for convenience. You can put your full path instead of `.` at the end and enjoy

Comment: I changed like this - "docker build -f Dockerfile -t spacestudykubernetes /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd/pipeline". But still I am getting error "unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd/Dockerfile: no such file or directory"

Comment: Because path to `Dockerfile` itself is evaluated from your `cwd`, not from context. User `docker build -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd/pipeline/Dockerfile -t spacestudykubernetes /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd/pipeline`

Comment: BTW this allows the `Dockerfile` to be located outside build context

Comment: I did not understood that , Dockerfile outside of context. I am new to this docker and ci/cd pipeline everything. Can you resolve my confusion that outside of context means?

Comment: Its working. Thanks. Can you update the latest answer ? Let me accept this as answer please. And can you clarify the confusion that I above asked?